# Remove last zero digits in groovy in ReadyApi

Tags: groovy, ready-api

I am trying to remove the last zero digits in groovy in my ReadyApi test.

For example,

273.900 needs to be 273.9

17.580 needs to be 17.58

116.000 needs to be 116

I have the following but this is not complete:

```
def qTY = context.expand( '${Stock DataSource#QTY}' )
qTY = qTY.replaceAll('.000', '')
qTY = qTY.replaceAll('00', '')
return qTY
```

Could someone help me tp write this more efficient?
Thank you

Comment: What does "is not complete" mean. Please provide the input that fails and how it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relatively simple regex for this:

```
'273.002000'.replaceFirst( /((?<=(\..{0,20}))0+)$/, '' ).replaceFirst( /\.$/, '' )
```

prints

> 273.002

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
def elideZeros(s) {
  s.reverse().dropWhile { it in ['0', '.'] }.reverse()
}

assert elideZeros('273.900') == '273.9'
assert elideZeros('17.580')  == '17.58'
assert elideZeros('116.000') == '116'
```